# How to get an object property value from an array using the value of another property

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I want to get the value of a property from an array of objects using the value of another property let's say I have the following array:

```
const objArray = 
  [
    {car: 'BMW', price: 2000},
    {car: 'VW', price: 3500}, 
    {car: 'FORD', price: 4000}
 ]
```

Is it possible to access (get) the price using the car value ?
Something like: objArray.car['BMW'].price ?

Comment: what do you mean by **without storing it in a const or var**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this meet your demand?
In my opinion,the car must store in a variable or pass it as a parameter

```js
const objArray = 
  [
    {car: 'BMW', price: 2000},
    {car: 'VW', price: 3500}, 
    {car: 'FORD', price: 4000}
 ]
 
let price = objArray.filter(a => a.car =='VW').map(e => e.price)[0]
console.log(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const objArray = 
  [
    {car: 'BMW', price: 2000},
    {car: 'VW', price: 3500}, 
    {car: 'FORD', price: 4000}
 ]
 
 function costByMake(make) {
   return (objArray.find(o => o.car === make) || {price: 0}).price
 }
 
 console.log(costByMake('VW'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const objArray = 
  [
    {car: 'BMW', price: 2000},
    {car: 'VW', price: 3500}, 
    {car: 'FORD', price: 4000}
 ]

const obj = {};
objArray.forEach(e => {
 obj[e['car']] = e['price'];
})

let price = obj['VM'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the price using the car value but not the way you mentioned. Why not? I wanna explain it a little first.

objArray.car['BMW'].price;

Here you are trying to access an element of "objArray" (which is an array) using dot notation and passing the value "car['BMW']" which is not an index, that's why you can't get any element from "objArray", so the price doesn't exist here.

So the answer is you can first iterate over the array using (for loop, find method etc..... ) then you will be able to check every element of the array and you can check if any of them meets your demand (if the car property of the element has the value "BMW"), if it does then you can get the price property from that element (object).

```js
const objArray = [
    {car: 'BMW', price: 2000},
    {car: 'VW', price: 3500},
    {car: 'FORD', price: 4000}
]

const carObj = objArray.find(function getCar(item) {
    return item.car === 'BMW'; // return the first item that matches the condition
});

console.log(carObj.price); // 2000
```

Answer (score 0):

To have this syntax you have to use `Proxy` (note that you can omit quotes: `objArray.car.BMW.price`):

```js
objArray = mapArray(objArray);

console.log(objArray.car.BMW.price);

function mapArray(arr){
  return new Proxy(arr, {
    get(_, prop){
      if(!(prop in arr) && typeof prop !== 'number' && typeof arr[0] === 'object' && arr[0] && prop in arr[0]){
        return new Proxy(arr, {
          get(_, key){
            return arr.find(item => item[prop] === key);
          }
        });
      }
      return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script>
let objArray = 
  [
    {car: 'BMW', price: 2000},
    {car: 'VW', price: 3500}, 
    {car: 'FORD', price: 4000}
]
</script>
```

You can set the key prop ahead and omit it later:

```js
objArray = mapArray(objArray, 'car');

console.log(objArray.BMW.price);
console.log(objArray.VW.price);

function mapArray(arr, key){
  return new Proxy(arr, {
    get(_, prop){
      if(!(prop in arr) && typeof prop !== 'number'){
        return arr.find(item => item[key] === prop);
      }
      return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script>
let objArray = 
  [
    {car: 'BMW', price: 2000},
    {car: 'VW', price: 3500}, 
    {car: 'FORD', price: 4000}
]
</script>
```